# SQLite - Highest 60 second average in a time series?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to find the highest 60 second average over an hours worth of data in sqlite.

Here's what I got so far:

```
SELECT MAX(SELECT AVG(watts) 
             FROM tblworkoutdata d2
            WHERE d2.workoutsummaryid = d1.workoutsummaryid 
              AND d2.ticks BETWEEN d1.ticks AND d1.ticks + 60)) AS theMax 
  FROM tblworkoutdata d1
 WHERE workoutsummaryid = 198
```

Each tick represents a second.  "Watts" is the field that I'm trying to find the highest average.  WorkoutSummaryID just represents a workout.

The code above says too many parenthesis in sqlite.  Does anyone know how to get the highest 60 second average over a time series?

Comment: Well, for one thing: You **do** have one paranthesis too many (line 4 of your code)

Comment: Actually he has one missing in line 1... (Open bracket for the MAX function, and one for the beginning of the correlated sub-query.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have indeed got too many closing parenthesis in your statement. You are missing the opening parenthesis around the sub-query:

```
SELECT MAX((SELECT AVG(watts) 
            FROM tblworkoutdata d2
            WHERE d2.workoutsummaryid = d1.workoutsummaryid 
              AND d2.ticks BETWEEN d1.ticks AND d1.ticks + 60)) AS theMax 
FROM tblworkoutdata d1
WHERE workoutsummaryid = 198
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT MAX((SELECT AVG(watts) 
             FROM tblworkoutdata d2
            WHERE d2.workoutsummaryid = d1.workoutsummaryid 
              AND d2.ticks BETWEEN d1.ticks AND d1.ticks + 60)) AS theMax 
  FROM tblworkoutdata d1
 WHERE workoutsummaryid = 198
```